# could not get the addition result

Tags: javascript

I want to add the user input but there is something wrong. there is no errors but nothing happens. I want to make sure that the input is numbers and then add the two inputs together.

```js
function add() {
  
  var first = document.getElementById('first-number').value;        
  var second = document.getElementById('second-number').value;        

   
        firstMostBe = first;
        secondMostBe = second;
          var output;  
   if ((isNaN(firstMostBe)) || (isNaN(secondMostBe))){
     alert('one or both of the operands are not numbers');
   } else {
         output = firstMostBe + secondMostBe;
         return output;  
   } 
 
  var result = output; // place-holder, delete this and start over
  var output_field = document.getElementById('result');
  output_field.innerHTML = result;
}
```

```html
<h2>Three-Layer Handlers Exercises</h2>

<hr>

  
   

<script src="./handlers-calculator.js"></script>

first number: <input id='first-number' value=''></input><br>
second number: <input id='second-number' value=''></input> <br>
<button onclick='add()'>+</button> 
<button onclick='subtract()'>-</button> 
<button onclick='multiply()'>*</button> 
<button onclick='divide()'>/</button> <br>
<p id='result'></p>

<br><br>

<hr>  
<hr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to `return` from function and also convert input to number using Unary Plus `+`. You can make the code cleaner by

- Use an array `['first-number','second-number']` and `map()` and then destructure it.
- You don't need to assign the variables twice.

```js
function add() {
  
  var [first,second] = ['first-number','second-number'].map(x => +document.getElementById(x).value)  
  if ([first,second].some(x => isNaN(x))){
    alert('one or both of the operands are not numbers');
  } else {
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = first * second
  } 
}
```

```html
<h2>Three-Layer Handlers Exercises</h2>
<hr>
<script src="./handlers-calculator.js"></script>
  first number: <input id='first-number' value=''></input><br>
  second number: <input id='second-number' value=''></input> <br>
  <button onclick='add()'>+</button> 
  <button onclick='subtract()'>-</button> 
  <button onclick='multiply()'>*</button> 
  <button onclick='divide()'>/</button> <br>
  <p id='result'></p>
<br><br>
<hr>  
<hr>
```

The `['first-number','second-number'].map(x => +document.getElementById(x).value)` returns the array contain both values of both input. And then destructured. Is equivalent to:

```
var arr = ['first-number','second-number'].map(x => +document.getElementById(x).value);
var first = arr[0]
var second = arr[1]
```

Comment: could you please explain why the array declaration looks like this: var [first,second]

Comment: @ab2016d Its called [Destructuring Assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

Comment: @ab2016d See I have updated the answer with little more detail about that part.

Comment: you are the best. this is really insightful. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need the numerical value (with an [unary plus `+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus)) of the operands and you need to return early, if you have `NaN` values.

Later you need to assign the result of the operation to the target element.

Inbetween, you need not to return, because this prevents to run until the place where the result is assigned.

```js
function add() {
    var first = +document.getElementById('first-number').value,   // try to get a number
        second = +document.getElementById('second-number').value, // try to get a number
        output_field = document.getElementById('result');

    if (isNaN(first) || isNaN(second)) {
        alert('one or both of the operands are not numbers');
        return;                                                   // exit
    }

    output_field.innerHTML = first + second;
}
```

```html
<h2>Three-Layer Handlers Exercises</h2>
first number: <input id='first-number' value=''><br>
second number: <input id='second-number' value=''><br>
<button onclick='add()'>+</button> 
<button onclick='subtract()'>-</button> 
<button onclick='multiply()'>*</button> 
<button onclick='divide()'>/</button> <br>
<p id='result'></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function add() {

    var first = document.getElementById('first-number').value;
    var second = document.getElementById('second-number').value;


    firstMostBe = first;
    secondMostBe = second;
    var output;
    if (isNaN(firstMostBe) || isNaN(secondMostBe)) {
        alert('one or both of the operands are not numbers');
    } else {
        output = parseInt(firstMostBe) + parseInt(secondMostBe);// By defaut it is string need to convert to number
        // no need to return form here 
    }

    var result = output; // place-holder, delete this and start over
    var output_field = document.getElementById('result');
    output_field.innerHTML = result;
}
```

2 issues are there

1. You are returning in between of the function
2. You are not casting the values to Number (by default it is string)

Comment: thanks a lot. I actually figured out about the parseInt part. then with your note i realized i was terminating my func before it finishes it is work.